# Removing www when using https protocol in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, web, https

First I bought a multi-domains SSL certificate that doesn't allow wildcards (ex. *.mydomain.com).

When I want to connect to my website and if I go through https://mydomain.com it works fine. Now, if I go through https://www.mydomain.com I have a nice alert page from my browser saying I've got to add an exception, blahblahbla... So I understand I've got this alert because the SSL certificate doesn't manage **www** wildcard.

I decided to create a rule in htaccess in order to redirect user from https://www.mydomain.com to https://mydomain.com. But my browser seems not to understand this rule, and each time I go through https://www.mydomain.com I stay on https://www.mydomain.com.

Here is my rule :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

For information, I use Virtualmin to manage my domains.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `.htaccess` or `mod_rewrite` won't be of any help here in eliminating browser security warning.

Reason is that the SSL certificate negotiation happens well before `mod_rewrite` get a chance to kick in.

When you buy SSL cert I believe you get an option for cert being applicable for both www and non-www domains.